# Script no envía contenido celda referenciada

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Tengo una hoja que se llama Devoluciones y mediante una hoja auxiliar donde se importan los datos, te permite seleccionar por código de devolución y uno de los lotes que hay dentro de esa devolución (cada devolución puede tener uno o X lotes).
A seleccionar ambos datos, se cargan unas celdas con los datos relevantes para enviar un notificación por email.
Hasta aquí todo correcto, funcionó a la primera.

Por lo tanto, ahora me surgió la necesidad de hacer exactamente lo mismo, pero con otra tabla, con lo que dupliqué la hoja, creé una auxiliar igual a la pimera pero con los datos de otra tabla. Todo exactamente igual.
EL PROBLEMA: no envía el cuerpo del mensaje. Envía el Asunto correcto, a los contactos correctos, pero en el cuerpo del mensaje pone #N/A.
Probé a cambiar la definición de los rangos, a indicarlo por coordenadas... pero nada.
Finalmente se me ocurrió ir recortando para del menasaje (quitando referencias) hasta que se envió.
El mensaje lo envía mientras no indique una celda que contiene un `BUSCARV`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si redacto el mensaje con referencias a A2, B2 funciona correcto y lo envía.
Pero en cuanto quiero añadir lo que pone en C2 hasta F2, ahí el mensaje lo envía como #N/A.

Como véis, la fila 2 de las columnas C:F contienen una fómula así:

```
=BUSCARV(A2&B2;ImportRelease!C:G;4;0)
```

Lo que me explota la cabeza es que el valor lo encuentra tal y como se muestra en la tabla, y el mensaje lo redacta correctamente con los valores de esas celdas...
Simplemente, lo envía como #N/A, y si no hago referencia a ninguna de esas celdas de la C a la F (pero sí la A o B), lo envía correcto.

¿Alguien tiene idea o intuye que está pasando?

Como digo, tengo otra hoja exactamente igual de donde dupliqué esta, y esa funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Aunque las imágenes podrían ser útiles, el código, mensajes de error y valores se deben incluir como  texto. Por favor, edita esta publicación para ajustarla a las reglas de Stack Overflow en español.